# Finding Ajax Post URL Without Access to Source

Tags: php, ajax

How can I find the POST URL for a form that's being posted using ajax (action handlers are in PHP, but I doubt that matters too much in this case)?

Problem is I need to find out using an alternate method as I don't have access to the source.

Comment: Don't really get your question. Sounds like a firebug solution to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you can run the page, you could check with Live HTTP Headers or fiddler to see where the POST is going...

Comment: live http headers helped me figure it out, thank you for reminding me about that add-on!

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean you don't have access to the source? If the JavaScript Ajax call is executed, then you probably *do* have access to the code. It's probably just a bit tricky to find.

Use [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) to understand which request is happening.